# Adding a success message to a generic redirect view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I currently have a project where people can create posts. I want to display a message saying that a post has been Upvoted successfully however the SuccessMessageMixin isn't working. Ive tried other methods which is included in my code which I will post below. The SuccessMessageMixin works for other views. Im not sure why it isn't working for this View.

Redirect View where code DOES NOT  work

```
class PostUpvoteRedirect(SuccessMessageMixin, RedirectView):
    model = Post
    success_message = "Post was upvoted successfully"
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(
            Post,
            publish__year=self.kwargs['year'],
            publish__month=self.kwargs['month'],
            publish__day=self.kwargs['day'],
            slug=self.kwargs['post'],
        )
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if (user != None):
            if user in obj.Upvote.all():
                obj.Upvote.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.Upvote.add(user)
                if user in obj.Downvote.all():
                    obj.Downvote.remove(user)
            success_message = "Post was upvoted successfully"
        return url_
```

Code where it DOES work

```
class PostCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body']
    success_message = "Post was created successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to realise that

> SuccessMessageMixin hooks to form_valid which is not present on RedirectView to push its message to the user.

This is exactly why it works in the other method since those classes support `form_valid()` functionality.

You can see this well-written answer here on how you can enable it with `RedirectView` - [Success_url in django RedirectView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597554/success-url-in-django-redirectview)

Comment: The problem is that the UpvoteRedirect view isn't technically a form so there is no form to validate

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect View dont have request access, for use django message class in CLASS VIEWS you need to use 'SuccessMessageMixin':

    class AnyView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, RedirectView):
    """ LoginRequ... is for Login, SuccessMessage.. is for Message"""
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    logging.debug('Sending message')
    permanent = False
    query_string = True
    somequery = ModelSome.objects.all().filter(activate=True)
    success_url = "/"
    success_message = "%(something)s was succefull"
```

Check in [Django Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/) for more details!